# Memory mapped binary logging in C++

Tags: c++

I have a requirement to take a struct and dump it into a file for later use. It needs to be as fast as possible.

Having experimented with various solutions, I have come to the conclusion that `memcpy()` to a memory mapped (with hugepages) file is the fastest solution to the problem. Is there a better approach?

I have tried async logging but it 
1.) is at best as fast the synchronous memory mapped solution 
2.) has the added overhead of an extra thread (i am constrained on resources too :)

Comment: By "later use" do you mean later in the same execution or later when the program is executed again? In the later case you'll need to use `msync` to make the changes appear in the file (in case you use linux or other posix).

Comment: Are the structs PODs or non trivial classes?

Comment: @skyking : I meant I would use the data in a separate program for analysis. That part is not performance sensitive.

Comment: Will the first program terminate before the other program reads the data? In that case you could just flush the data on exit (or even just write the memory region to disk without memory mapping, if it's not to much data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_file):

```
#include <boost/interprocess/file_mapping.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/mapped_region.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

namespace ip = boost::interprocess;

struct example {
   int data;
   // etc.
};

const char * filename = "/path/to/file";
int main () {
   // Remove existing mapping
   ip::file_mapping::remove (filename);

   // Create file
   std::filebuf fb;
   fb.open(filename, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out
                          | std::ios_base::trunc | std::ios_base::binary);
   fb.pubseekoff (sizeof (example)-1,  std::ios_base::beg);
   fb.sputc (0);

   // Map to file
   ip::file_mapping mapping (filename, ip::read_write);

   // map a region
   ip::mapped_region region (mapping, ip::read_write);

   // Get mapped address
   void *addr = region.get_address( );

   // copy struct to file
   example ex;
   memcpy (addr, &ex, sizeof (example));

   // flush to disk
   region.flush ();
}
```

To get the data out, map to the file in the same way (although probably with just read_only access). The thing that might kill you here is the flush to disk which could take a while.

Ideally you should try the mapped file version and the simple iostream version from [Tanzer's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31934690/184741). Measure the performance of both on your target platform and select the best one.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. I am doing pretty much the same with standard C++ API. And if I am measuring correctly, this is the fastest it can go (fraction of a microsecond for 512 bytes message on the machine I measured). I am not doing the flush() though, letting the OS take care of that. Is flushing manually absolutely necessary? I don't mind if data is lost due to occasional crashes.

Comment: Flushing isn't strictly necessary. Also, depending on your platform it will probably be performed asynchronously anyway; calling `flush()` will just cause it to flush in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ifstream and ofstream classes to write your objects as binary to a file.

```
struct anyobj;

ofstream ofs("file.bin",ios::binary);
ofs.write ((char*) & anyobj , sizeof(anyobj));
```

Then read

```
struct anyobj2;

ifstream ifs ("file.bin", ios::binary);
ifs.read((char*) & anyobj2 , sizeof(anyobj2));
```

But you should take care on situations like different systems (portability) and compilers ( different padding strategies).